# Angular 10 - Assign a FormArray to FormGroup in template

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am creating a FormArray like this in my component:

(This is simplified code to illustrate my question...)

```
form: FormArray;
dataModel = [
        { fname: 'test1', lname: 'test1' },
        { fname: 'test2', lname: 'test2' },
        { fname: 'test3', lname: 'test3' }
    ]

....further in component...

this.form = this.fb.array(this.dataModel);
```

Then in the template I am using it like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let item of dataModel.items; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="text" formControlName="fname">
            <input type="text" formControlName="lname">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I think I am a bit surprised that this works, but ...formGroup and formArray both extend from AbstractControl which is why I can pass formArray to [formGroup] in the template... and [formGroupName] points to the current index of the formArray... so my question is: Is it ok the way this is set up?